# What are docker networks are needed for?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Please explain why `docker network` is needed? I read some documentation, but on a practical example, I don't understand why we need to manipulate the `network`. Here I have a `docker-compose` in which everything works fine with and without `network`. Explain me please, what benefits will be in practical use if you uncomment `docker-compose` in the right places? Now my containers interact perfectly, there are migrations from the ORM to the database, why do I need a `networks`?

```
 version: '3.4'

services:
  main:
    container_name: main
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:${PORT}
    command: npm run start:dev
    env_file:
      - .env
#     networks:
#       - webnet
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:12
#     networks:
#       - webnet
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE_NAME}
      PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
# networks:
#   webnet:
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

Comment: In your example there's not much difference. Without the network definitions, docker-compose still creates a network for your containers.

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for _narrow, specific_ questions about problems encountered while writing code. General computing questions are a better fit for [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no networks are defined, docker-compose will create a default network with a generated name. Otherwise you can manually specify the network and its name in the compose file.

You can read more at [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Answer (score 1):

Without config network for containers, all container IPs are in one range (Ex. 172.17.0.0/16). also, they can see each other by name of the container (Docker internal DNS).

**Simple usage of networking in docker:**

When you want to have numbers of containers in a specific network range isolated, you must use the network of docker.

Answer (score 0):

Here explained Docker network - [Networking overview](https://docs.docker.com/network/), and here are tutorials:

[Macvlan network tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-macvlan/),

[Overlay networking tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-overlay/),

[Host networking tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/),

[Bridge network tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/).